# Error when using debugging under Atollic TrueStudio / STM32

Tags: debugging, configuration, st-link, truestudio, atollic

I'm using

- STM32F103C8T6
- Atollic TrueStudio
- STLink2.1

Error I get when debugging:

[image]

Debug configuration set in TrueStudio:

[image]

What worked before was in SW4STM32/Eclipse, with the following settings. I always had to change the reset mode from Connect under Reset to Software System Reset. However, this option is not available in the debug configuration of True Studio.

What can I do to use debugging successfully with STLink2.1 on Atollic TrueStudio?

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer elsewhere but I will repeat it here for other people:

- Close Atollic TrueStudio (not sure if this is needed)
- Startup ST Utility
- Press the Reset button and keep it pressed
- Select Erase Chip (in Target menu)
- Release the Reset button
- The chip is erased
- Close ST Utility
- Startup Atollic TrueStudio

Debug should work now

Comment: Saved me a lot of trouble, thanks!